# Как обработать json,parse()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь разобраться с ajax. Отправил запрос, когда заполнил форму, в ответ получил данные `json_encode()`

В ответ ко мне на html страницу приходит запрос, я делаю

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#form');
    form.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Добавили, чтобы страница не перезагружалась
        $.ajax({
            url: 'script.php',
            type: 'POST',                        
            data: form.serialize(), // Передаём данные
            success: function(response) {
                var result = JSON.parse(response);
                $('.pas').attr('style', '');
                var password_1 = result['0'];
                $("#bots").html(password_1);
                console.log(password_1);

            },
        });
    })
});
```

Но он его не хочет выводить на страницу. Смотрю в консоли, я получаю такую строку
`{password: "hello"}`
Как мне оттуда вытащить **hello**?

Comment: `{password: "hello"}` - обьект, `result.password`

Comment: А если мне приходит их неск штук? [{"password":"hello"},{"password":"down"}] Как к ним обращаться?

Comment: `result[0].password`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Спасибо!